# jQuery Sortable with box-sizing:border-box

Tags: jquery-ui

I've found that if an element has "box-sizing: border-box" when using jquery's sortable implementation it losses/changes its size when dragged.

example -

http://jsfiddle.net/veBJh/2/

If you remove the box-sizing:border-box attribute it will work as expected, keeping the original elements dimensions. Is there any way around this (minus changing the box-sizing attribute, it's a global setting on the project and I'd rather not remove it as it makes everything else so much simpler!)?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by adding a custom 'helper' to the sortable call:

```
$('#container').sortable({
    helper: function(event, element) {
      var clone = $(element).clone();
      var w = $(element).outerWidth();
      var h = $(element).outerHeight();
      clone.css({
          'width': w+'px',
          'height': h+'px'
        });
      return clone;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved adding a `box-sizing: content-box;` to the draggable item