# Jquery UI Resizable with box-sizing: "border-box" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm currently using Jquery resizable ( http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/ )

and I have noticed that it does not work well with "box-sizing: border-box;".

I have googled it and couldn't get the solid answer.. (maybe I haven't spent enough time..)

Someone already posted an example of a problem exactly same as mine on js fiddle already:

```
(http://jsfiddle.net/muNjL/)
```

I'm not sure if solution to this issue is out yet...

If I have no option but to not use border-box, please let me know. I will be very appreciated.

Thank you for reading and happy coding!

-Danny C

Answer (score 0):

Why are you `border-box`ing everything? Normalization?

Try JSFiddle's Normalize CSS under the Fiddle Options on the left. I assume it loads [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Then remove all your border-box declarations. Your resizable should now expand [to the entire width and height of the parent container](http://jsfiddle.net/muNjL/1/).

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #888;
}

#container #ohboxme {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The js-fiddle link that I attached is not exactly my code.. it is just to reference the problem that I'm having right now. I'm currently using border-box attribute in the div that will get re-size.

so, to be more precise, box-sizing: border-box; is defined in #ohboxme only for my case.  

I do know the fact that removing border-box will remove the problem that I'm having right now, but I wanted to know if there is a way to use jquery resize along with "border-box".

Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295071/jquery-sortable-with-box-sizingborder-box for a helper function which allows you to keep border box.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with jqueryui resizable ... see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8932
The best solution for now is to switch to using css 'outline' instead of 'border'.
Essentially if you set a border then it alters the value returned by jquery's width() function. This means that the resizeable widget thinks the box is smaller than it actually is.